# how to use for loops inside OptionMenu widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following optionMenu `om = OptionMenu(mygroup3, v, name).pack()` and the for loops :

```
for row in result: 
id = row[0]
name = row[1]
```

it make the following code :

```
from tkinter import *
from connectdb import *
app = Tk()
global mygroup3
mygroup3 = LabelFrame(app, text='new div').pack()
Label(mygroup3, text='group3').pack()
select_Class = ("select id,name from class")
cursor.execute(select_Class)
result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
    id = row[0]
    nom = row[1]
    mygroup3 = Label(app, text=nom).pack()
    v = StringVar()
    v.set(nom)
    om = OptionMenu(mygroup3, v, nom)
    om.pack()
```

the code make as much optionMenu than my table records cause my optionMenu widget is on my for loop but when i put my OptionMenu outside i have only the last records registred . 
So how can i use the OptionMenu tu show all my records ?

Comment: I would suggest to make list box or links for each row, on click of which you can launch `OptionMenu` or just a grid with `entry` or labels having all those details.

Comment: it is a possibility, however I thought to create a list with checkbox according to the speed of the dropdown, it may complicate things and make the process less dynamic. It's imposible with a dropdown?

Comment: Well dropdown is also good choice, showing one key field from the row later having other entry/labels to show other details on selection of item from dropdown.

Comment: yes but i cant do that cause my OptionMenu need to show all the result of the loop and i can see only the last record, i tried to put the OptionMenu before or after the loop but nothing is good. It is possible to got a for loop inside a tkinter object?

Comment: Try printing `row` on console and check if you are geting all desired rows, meanwhile commentout those relevant lines for OptionMenu

Comment: i did print(name) inside my for loop it work and print all my record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution i just needed to convert my for loop result into a sting with `mylist.append(str(row[1]))` and truncate the result of the list with `*mylist` in OptionMenu